# Adjusting text and image size to different resolutions

Tags: css, resolutions

I've been making a website using % in nearly everything so it fits on smaller screens.

I'm just at a loss for making text adjust to a different size wtihout it looking shitty on bigger resolutions. I also can't seem to max-width images I use as a menubar.

Any of you that could help me out via some CSS commands?

Example of text CSS and image CSS:

```css
#dick{
 color: black;
 z-index: 400;
 position:absolute;
 left: 58%;
    top: 210px;
    height: 50%;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:100%;

}

#startpagina{
  background-image: url("images/startpagina.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 19.1%;
  top: 192px;
  height: 0%;
  z-index: 200;
  max-width:100%
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example on how I could it implent it into my existing code?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width:600px) {
    #dick {
    font-size:15px;
    }
}
```

Experiment with it to get desired results.